# newenvironment, label, indentation

Tags: environments, indentation

I have a custom environment that I reference. It seems that the indentation changes if I do not include a space before `\label` (see MWE below). So, I have a few questions:

1. Should it matter where `\label` is placed on a custom environment; could the environment be changed so that I don't have to put a space before `\label`?
2. Is there a convention on where `\label` should be placed (on non-floating environments), or is this a matter of style?
3. Is there a preferred way of getting a line break rather than using `\newline`?

Please note that I do not want to use `ntheorem` as the actual version I use takes 2 optional arguments (using `newenvironmentx` from `xargs`).

**EDIT**: 
I am particularly interested in trying to answer my first question- could the definition of the environment be changed so that I don't have to put a space before `\label`, or a `%` after it? The `ntheorem` package seems to accomplish it using `trivlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}%
{%
    \refstepcounter{problem}%
    \textbf{Problem \theproblem }\newline%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\label{firstlabel}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{problem}

\begin{problem} \label{secondlabel}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. See 3.
2. The convention is to put it after a `\caption[..]{...}`, or more accurately, after `\refstepcounter{...}` for correct labelling. Otherwise the label would refer to a previous instance of the most recent `\refstepcounter{...}` that was executed.
3. Use `\par` or `\endgraf` instead of `\newline`.

[image: Newenvironment using \par]

Comment: Thanks; if I use \par, I get the same skip as \parskip, which I don't want, unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: @smr01cmh: You're right. Using `\par` or `\endgraf` inserts a `\parskip`. To avoid this is not so much a problem in the macro but in your `problem` environment. You need a `%` right after the `\label{...}`, otherwise LaTeX uses the line break in your code as an extra space.

Comment: Thanks again; so it seems that I can either put a space before the \label, or % after it. I was hoping for a solution within the definition of the environment. When using a custom environment from `ntheorem` it doesn't have to be as delicate- i.e, no need for space before or % after

Answer (score 2):

I just saw this post because I have the same question when I am referencing a custom environment. Based on all the above information, I found a solution to solve the problem. You only need to slightly modify the definition of the environment as follows:

```
\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}%
{%
    \refstepcounter{problem}%
    \textbf{Problem \theproblem } \par\vspace{-\parskip}%
}{}
```

My explanation: when using `\par` instead of `\newline` or `\\`, you don't have to put a space before `\label`, or a `%` after it. But in the meantime, `\par` leads to `\parskip`. Thus, you have to put `\vspace{-\parskip}` right after `\par`.

I also expect any other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add comment characters `%` immediatly after the closing braces of the `\label{...}` arguments. This will prevent the spaces you saw.

That's where I put my labels in an environment, theorem, etc. But like Werner said you wont get the right cross references.

Have you looked at the `amsthm` package for making theorem like environments.

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}                % Name
  {}                                     % Space above
  {}                                     % Space below
  {}                                     % Body font
  {}                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}                            % Theorem head font
  {.}                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}                             % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {}                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\label{firstlabel}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem} \label{secondlabel}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Oh and that will give you the right cross referencing.

Comment: Thanks; I don't want to use a theorem environment for this, as the actual version uses `newenvironmentx` and has 2 optional arguments.